# Strange Issue with Wordpress Post Array in Admin Panel

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I am incredibly confused over an issue with the Post Array on a Wordpress Site I am building for a client. I'm hoping someone has seen this before!

I have registered a Custom Post Type:

```
register_post_type( 'products', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', ),
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products','with_front' => TRUE),
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'product_page_meta_box'
));
```

Within which I have registered a callback for the following meta box:

```
function product_page_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('product_meta_box_content', 'Product Specifications',  'product_meta_box_content', 'products');
}

function product_meta_box_content( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'product_noonce' );

    echo '<div class="inside>';
        var_dump($post);
        echo '<p>Please detail the product specifics here:</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

The frustration I have is that the result of the var_dump above on the admin page is:

```
string(3) "258" ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2012-08-27 19:33:30" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2012-08-27 19:33:30" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(10) "The Wensum" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(20) "Testing the excerpt!" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(22) "large-6-perch-dovecote" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2012-10-04 16:50:19" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2012-10-04 16:50:19" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> string(1) "0" ["guid"]=> string(53) "http://dovecotes.local//?post_type=products&p=258" ["menu_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["post_type"]=> string(8) "products" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["ancestors"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> string(4) "edit" }
```

In the admin area it has no type and is completely invalid; on the the page concerned though the post array is fine, the ID has a key and it is a valid object:

```
object(stdClass)#145 (25) { ["ID"]=> int(258) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2012-08-27 19:33:30" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2012-08-27 19:33:30" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(10) "The Wensum" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(20) "Testing the excerpt!" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(22) "large-6-perch-dovecote" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2012-10-04 16:50:19" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2012-10-04 16:50:19" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(54) "http://dovecotes.local//?post_type=products&p=258" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(8) "products" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["ancestors"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't guarantee this will work, but I've always avoided using the 'register_meta_box_cb' when defining custom post types in favor of the 'add_meta_boxes' action hook.

Apart from the extra comma in your 'supports' parameter, your code looks right, so nothing in your example would lead me to believe that any of it could be the culprit unless it's a prioritization discrepancy. I'm also not sure if the id and callback parameters are allowed to be identical in your metabox arguments, so I took the liberty of changing that too:

```
register_post_type( 'products', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products','with_front' => TRUE)
));
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'product_page_meta_box');
function product_page_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('product_meta_box_content', 'Product Specifications',  'product_meta_box_content_cb', 'products');
}

function product_meta_box_content_cb( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'product_noonce' );

    echo '<div class="inside>';
        var_dump($post);
        echo '<p>Please detail the product specifics here:</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

If that doesn't help, then I'm not sure what else it would be without seeing more code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply @maiorano84.

I have tried it both ways and unfortunately the result is the same, what code do you think would help?

Comment: Sorry, missed the part regarding the callback and ID will change these in a moment and let you know if it helps!